# Create a view block for display of taxonomy term children

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I am trying to create a View of Taxonomy Terms which lists the child terms for the currently displayed term.  Is this even possible for taxonomy terms or is it only possible for Content Nodes?

Answer (score 1):

yes,you can do this by :
on CONTEXTUAL FILTERS add "Taxonomy term: Parent term" and on once you've chosen it, there's a set of radio buttons entitled When the filter value is NOT available. Set this to provide a default value and then, in this case, choose "Taxonomy term id from url" from the drop-down menu.you are good to go.

Comment: tnx for your solution "Shirin", This is good solution , who down vote this ? !!!

Comment: you're welcome.I really don't know why somebody would do that ! :(

Comment: Sometimes there is discrimination , anyway I think your solution is good and correct, he/she should not down vote it, I upvote your answer ;)  I am glad to see IRANINAN DRUPAL DEVELOPER girl here :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a contextual filter by making a new View and add a Block Display to it. From there you add the contextual field of Taxonomy to parse the URL path. Then pass an argument into the contextual filter which selects the Taxonomy vocabulary. From there you add in the fields you want to show.

Watch this as it will help you out on setting up a contextual filter: http://nodeone.se/en/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-19-contextual-filters-with-paths

Comment: What you describe would be selecting terms of the same vocabulary.  I'm trying to select terms that have, as their parent_id, the term id of the current term from the URL.